# Issue with @ConditionalOnProperty

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-integration

I need some help in the understanding usage of @ConditionalOnProperty in spring boot. My requirement is to start cron jobs on only one node using @@Scheduled annotation. I am setting a system property programmatically using node IP

```
@Component("interation")
 public class IntegrationConfiguration {

private @Value("${integration.prinarynode}") 
String PRIMARY_NODE ;

private final Logger log = LoggerFactory.getLogger(IntegrationConfiguration.class);
@PostConstruct
   public void setProperty() {
    String ip = null;
    try {
        ip = InetAddress.getLocalHost().getHostAddress();
    } catch (UnknownHostException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    log.debug("Primary Nod:"+PRIMARY_NODE);
      if(PRIMARY_NODE == null || ip.equals(PRIMARY_NODE))
      {
          log.debug("Setting integrations true");
          System.setProperty("exception.clearance.allowed", "true");
      } else {
          System.setProperty("exception.clearance.allowed", "false");
      }
   }
}
```

and my scheduled code

```
@DependsOn ({"integration"})
@Component
@ConditionalOnProperty(prefix = "exception.clearance", name="allowed", matchIfMissing = false)
public class ScheduledTasks {

    private final Logger log = LoggerFactory.getLogger(ScheduledTasks.class);

    /** The services. */

    @Autowired
    // this is to 
    private IntegrationConfiguration intConfig;



    @Scheduled(fixedRate = 5000)

    public void ExceptionClear() {
        log.debug("in the sc task");

    }

}
```

method ExceptionClear is cron method and it should execute only on one node

Answer (score 0):

In fact you set the property **after** ScheduledTasks bean initializing. The changing in `@PostConstruct` is futile.

Instead I would suggest to add your own PropertyCondition

```
public class PropertyCondition implements Condition {
    @Override
    public boolean matches(ConditionContext context, AnnotatedTypeMetadata metadata) {
        return ... place your root detecting logic here ...
    }
}
```

and use it to annotate class

```
@Conditional(PropertyCondition.class)
```